# How to not show file path with dir /b /s command in batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, dir

Is there Any way I can bypass displaying file paths when using the `dir /b /s` command into a file? 
Currently, when I run `dir /b /s C:\WinPE_amd64 >dir.txt` it outputs something like this:

```
C:\WinPE_amd64\file.txt
C:\WinPE_amd64\secondfile.txt
C:\WinPE_amd64\Folder\AnotherFile.txt
```

What I want is something like this:

```
file.txt
secondfile.txt
AnotherFile.txt
```

Comment: Omit  the `/S` **If** there are files in subdirs with the same name how would you distinguish them? Otherwise parse dir output with a `for /f` and use the `~nx` modifier to return only name+extension `for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S "C:\WinPE_amd64"') do @Echo=%~nxA`

Comment: My Dir Command need not distinguish them since I then sort out new and old files. That is perfect thank you. Maybe post that as an answer so you get credit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse dir output with a `for /f` and use the `~nx` modifier to return only name+extension

On the cmd line:

```
(for /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /B/S "C:\WinPE_amd64"') do @Echo=%~nxA)>dir.txt
```

In a batch double the percent sign of the for metavariable

```
@Echo off
( for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /B/S "C:\WinPE_amd64"') do Echo=%%~nxA
) >dir.txt
```

It is a matter of formatting preference (or to avoid overly long lines)

```
@Echo off
( for /f "delims=" %%A in (
    'dir /B/S "C:\WinPE_amd64"'
  ) do Echo=%%~nxA
) >dir.txt
```

**EDIT a possibly faster alternative is a `for /r`**

```
(For /r "C:\WinPE_amd64" %A in (*) Do @Echo=%~nxA)>dir.txt
```

Another alternative wrapping a powershell command

```
powershell -nop -c "(dir 'C:\WinPE_amd64' -r -file).Name" >dir.txt
```

Comment: The only problem is that this is a very slow script for a 2,000 line DIR.

Comment: still, probably the best Ill get from a batch

Comment: Parsing with `for /f` involves a second instance of cmd.exe. I add another way to the answer